# Practices for refactoring unit tested code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
public void AddEntry(Entry entry)
{
    if (entry.Size < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Entry size must be greater than zero");
    DB.Entries.Add(entry);
}
```

And a corresponding unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException), "Entry size must be greater than zero")]
public void AddEntry_TermSizeLessThanZero_ThrowException()
{
    Entry e = new Entry(-5);

    AddEntry(e);
}
```

And then I refactor the validation code out:

```
public void AddEntry(Entry entry)
{
    Validate(entry);
    DB.Entries.Add(entry);
}

public void Validate(Entry entry)
{
    if (entry.Size < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Entry size must be greater than zero");
}
```

The unit test no longer describes the validation code.

What's the best thing to do in this case? Do I just leave Validate() to be tested through AddEntry?

Edit: to clarify, supposing I had a reason to make the refractored code public (a bit contrived in this situation), would I want to duplicate the test code to be thorough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point I wouldn't add a test to Validate(), since that code is already hit by an existing test.  I like that test since it corresponds closely to the class's requirements.

This changes when you start using Validate() in other functions in the class, or in other classes.  Validate() may also be extended to validate different issues, you'll want to address this.

When Validate() has multiple callers, and Validate() starts testing multiple conditions, you'll probably want:

- 1 Validate() test per validation condition
- 1 test per call to Validate

  - you might verify someone calls Validate by passing in one of the failure conditions

    - upside of this approach is less fake abstraction
    - downside is those tests could all become invalid if the Validate() criteria changes
    - consider putting the code generating the invalid input in a test utility method
  - you might also verify someone calls Validate by passing in a mock object for the validator

    - upside of this approach is decoupling of what is validated versus who is doing the validation, making tests more robust versus some changes
    - downside is yet another layer of abstraction making the code more complex

It seems adding tests in this manner keeps good coverage while scaling linearly with the number of requirements tested.

Comment: Lots of good answers, but I guess there is no one answer for this problem.

I've never thought too much about the second approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Since you made the `Validate()` method a public member of your object (for whatever reason) you should certainly add a seperate test for it. The test for `AddEntry` should remain in place.

A unit test should only test the interface of a unit and shall not assume any implementation details. So in this case you should leave your test for `AddEntry` in place the way it is, because it describes the behavior of your interface. But you should not assume or test that `AddEntry()` calls `Validate()`.

Comment: You should also consider to make `Validate()` private and best practice is to test only public interface.

Comment: Hmm, that's actually what sort of baffles me.

This is a bit of a contrived example to make a Validate() public, but if I had a reason to refractor a function and make it public, would it make sense to duplicate the test code?

I want to make sure that the original function still calls Validate(), so I still need to test at least a portion of the Validate() behavior there, and then I want to test Validate() itself as well.

If I were to provide the tests as documentation for another programmer, I would have to inform him to use Validate(), and possibly test all its behavior in the caller.

Comment: *You don't care* whether the original function calls Validate() -- you only care that it validates.  The implementation of that validation is irrelevant to your test.  If you have a reason to make it public, then you should also have a contract of some kind (saying what should go in, what should come out, and what the function guarantees will or won't happen), and you'd base your tests on that.

Comment: @cHao: That's exactly what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

As this code evolves, there are two possibilities:

1. `Validate()` stays simple and acts as a private helper, of which external callers (including tests) should not be aware. In this case, `Validate()` should not have its own tests, but instead have its behavior tested through other methods that call it.
2. `Validate()` becomes complex enough that you have to duplicate a lot of test code to verify that it is called in each place it should be. In this case, I would consider extracting an interface+class to perform the validation. `Validate()` can then be tested thoroughly in its new home and a fake `IValidator` (or whatever) can be used in your test of `AddEntry`, asserting that `Validate()` is called as necessary.